# Vue.js input suggestions visible when input is focused and @click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I a having a small issue with my app. I display search suggestion only when the input is focused using v-show and @focus like this

```
//input
@focus="shouldShowSuggestions = true"
@blur="shouldShowSuggestions = false"

//suggestions div
v-show="shouldShowSuggestions"
```

When I focus on the input the suggestions are shown correctly but when I try to click on a suggestion the link is not clicked and suggestions disappear due to the @blur I have.

I know the issue but I am not sure how to handle it. Any ideas?

I created a pen with the problem in case it is not clear. 
To reproduce just, focus on the input and try to click on a suggestion.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrdavv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A click event consists of a mouse down and up action. The input will be blurred on mouse down, therefore it will be hidden before the click event would occur.

Try using the `mousedown` event instead of `click` to catch it earlier (but this probably won't work on touch devices).

Or, even better, you could prevent the `mousedown` event from blurring the focused element:

```vue
<a @mousedown.prevent @click="clickedElement">
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you

Answer (score -2):

There are several things missing:

1. Input field is missing `v-model`. You need to bind the `input` field to a `data` attribute in order to be *reactive*. Read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage).
2. Pass the `suggestion` to the `@click` event attached in the suggestions div.

Here is the updated [codepen link.](https://codepen.io/josteph22/pen/wXyEWM)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer does not resolve the main issue with blur.